# What is the origin of "journal" to mean a mechanical shaft?

Tags: etymology, british-english

What is the origin of "journal" to mean a mechanical shaft? A more common modern use is in "journal bearing" which refers to the sliding surface between a rotating shaft and a hole it passes through and supports it relative to some other component.

Comment: Why is this tagged British English specifically? Have you established the phrase definitely originated there?

Comment: No, but I had to put a tag, I speak british english, and don't know if it's common elsewhere, feel free to edit.

Comment: Well looks like it did anyway from StoneyB's answer!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[*OED 1*](http://archive.org/stream/newenglishdicpt205murruoft#page/606/mode/2up), 10, says

> in *Machinery*.  The part of a shaft or axle which rests on the bearings. (Sometimes erroneously identified with ‘bearing’.)
>     Originally used in a more restricted application: ‘It was proposed by Buchanan, in his *Treatise on Millwork*, to apply the word *gudgeon* only to the bearing part at the end of a shaft or axle, which is exposed to bending action alone, and not twisting action; and *journal* to an intermediate bearing part through which a twisting moment is or may be exerted; but the custom of using the word “journal” in both senses indiscriminately is so prevalent, that it is impracticable to carry out Buchanan’s suggestion’. (Rankine *Machinery & Millwork* (1869) III.iii. § 460.) [*Journal* or *journey* in this sense seems to have arisen in the Scotch workshops. **No explanation of its origin has been found**.] (*my emphasis*)

I'm going to guess that it originally designated the part which moves → travels → ‘journeys’ in contact with the bearing; but I have no evidence at all for that derivation.

Answer (score 0):

Journal is related to the word "diurnal" and these words originally referred specifically to the journey or daily movement of the sun... or in other words to the rotation of the Earth. This may be the connection to cyclical rotary motion in particular.

Comment: Also the possibility of "daily" lubrication...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe related to what I found on Google

[jour·nal](https://%3Chttps://www.google.com/search?q=journal%20meaning&newwindow=1&rlz=1C1GCEJ_enUS999US1000&sxsrf=AB5stBjtiFNyubzJgX1L1d_F8yjLRGwxig%3A1689030393561&ei=-Y6sZM_rIaev5NoPufaLqAU&oq=journal%20&gs_lp=Egxnd3Mtd2l6LXNlcnAiCGpvdXJuYWwgKgIIAjIHECMYigUYJzIEECMYJzIHECMYigUYJzIHEAAYigUYQzIHEAAYigUYQzIHEAAYigUYQzIHEAAYigUYQzIHEAAYigUYQzIHEAAYigUYQzIHEAAYigUYQ0j2JVCeCVi0EHABeAGQAQCYAdYBoAHhBqoBBTEuNS4xuAEByAEA-AEBwgIHECMYsAMYJ8ICChAAGEcY1gQYsAPCAgoQABiKBRiwAxhDwgIFEAAYgATCAg0QABiABBgUGIcCGLEDwgIFEC4YgATiAwQYACBBiAYBkAYK&sclient=gws-wiz-serp%3E)

Origin

late Middle English (originally denoting a book containing the appointed times of daily prayers): from Old French jurnal, from late Latin diurnalis (see diurnal).

[di·ur·nal](https://%3Chttps://www.google.com/search?newwindow=1&rlz=1C1GCEJ_enUS999US1000&sxsrf=AB5stBiGLFebI0xF6eaqaCC1DYqFr1fIQQ:1689030685352&q=diurnal&si=ACFMAn_otZSKbpzAqD_RvWk4YSL-7bL7cZyCcjnaM1HNszdu4FmJOKpAWY9LvlGdQDcY9sxRTfr2AY9Ro_QSBb1kwUVbgHxxXg%3D%3D&expnd=1&biw=1745&bih=852&dpr=1.1%3E)

2.
daily; of each day.
"diurnal rhythms"

ASTRONOMY
of or resulting from the daily rotation of the earth.
"diurnal aberration"

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).